# Twitter bootstrap absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using TWBootstrap with span3 and span4 columns.  I want to align the text in span3 to the bottom of image in span9.  I think I have achieved this but feel I've thrown in the kitchen sink to do it.  Also I don't understand why the TWB span sizes aren't working?  For example how do I get the leftcol text to right aligned and to the edge of this column? Could someone please explain - I seem to be going round in circles.   The example is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBB3/bZshC/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="leftcol">
        <span class="span4">
          <h1>Right</h1>
          <h4>Enter</h4>
        </span>
      </div>
      <span id="mainpic" class="span8 box">
          <p align="middle">green box </p>                <p align="middle">representing image</p>
      </span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body { height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; }
h1 h4 {  text-align:right; }
#main { position:relative; background:red; height:400px; width:300px; }
#leftcol { position:absolute; background:blue; bottom:5px;}
#mainpic { position:absolute; background:green; top:10px; left:25%; }
.box { height: 370px; width: 300px; border: solid 10px #ccc; }
```

Comment: The fiddle you provided doesn't include the bootstrap.css .. You should add this, or try http://bootply.com instead

Comment: Thanks @Skelly I've reworked this code now using this bootply (its great!)  http://bootply.com/60827 but I would appreciate your comments on the code.  All I want to do is to force the text in the leftcol to the bottom to align with the adjacent column. The simplicity of which is eluding me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you are using the right tool for the job? You've wrapped all your content in a main div that you have given a width of 300px. In addition to some other problems, at this width bootstrap collapses to a single stacked column.

Comment: I've reworked this code using the bootply.com  and have it working but I still think the code could be simpler. http://bootply.com/60827